# Meteor NGinx Bad Gateway

Tags: node.js, nginx, meteor

He,

I'm running a MeteorJS setup on nodeJs with NGinX.
When I'm visiting the website, There's nothing wrong.

When Google Tries to visit it, there is nothing returned and I see that my access.log reads a Bad Gateway error.

I've tried spiderable and lufrai's version of spiderable, but that didn't help either.
My NGinX has websocket activity, so that ain't it either..

Could someone point me in the right direction?

> Server block
>
> ```
> server {
>    listen 80;
>
>    server_name $name;
>    root $rootDir;
>
>    passenger_enabled on;
>    passenger_sticky_sessions on;
> }
> ```

Even PhantomJS is installed AND is in the right path.

Comment: Please include any relevant code: your nginx `server` block at least (I don't know anything about Meteor)

Comment: Have you installed phantomjs? I think it is required for spiderable

Comment: As added above, phantomJS is installed + in the right path dir and I've included my server block.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this location block to the server block:

```
server {
   listen 80;

   server_name $name;
   root $rootDir;

   passenger_enabled on;
   passenger_sticky_sessions on;

   location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:PORT;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help k.chao.0424, unfortunately it does nothing for me. Could it be that it's occurs because the app is behind a loadbalancer??

Comment: Do you have anything in your /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf?

Comment: This is a long shot, but did you reload your nginx after editing your config? `sudo nginx -s reload`

Comment: No, I dont even have that nginx route in my local user and I just tried reloading it, but the outcome stays the same.. 

[alert] 2967#0: *2329 768 worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: staging.veluwseheksen.nl, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:80/", host: "localhost"